# selectbox combined value in laravel view page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a selectbox which has two field combined value as single option 
eg :name1(name1_code),name2(name2_code) and populated this value from ajax call response. I have single form for submit form and edit page.If I have a `$id` I want to populate the value in select box.I have tried as

```
js code
$.each(data, function(key, value) {     //populate value 
   $('#project_name').append($("<option></option>")
   .text(value).attr("value",key)); 
});
```

Php

```
if(isset($id))          
{
 $types=DB::table('sow_mapping as m')->leftJoin('sow as s','m.sow_id','=','s.id')->leftJoin('project as p','p.id','=','m.project_id')->where('p.code','=',$asset_request->project_code)->pluck('s.number','s.code')->all();
 $sow_code=db::table('sow')->where('code',$asset_request->sow)->value('number');
 echo Form::select('sow_name',
    [''=>'Select']+$types,$asset_request->sow.'('.$sow_code.')',['class'=>'selectpicker default','id'=>'sow_name']);
 }



print_r($types) output as 
   Array ( [SOW_1395] => WJT - SOW 07 ) 

 I want to print as  `SOW_1395(WJT - SOW 07)`
```

Is it possible to print as  `SOW_1395(WJT - SOW 07)`

Answer (score 0):

You can append the key with value

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {     //populate value 
   $('#project_name').append($("<option></option>")
   .text(key+'('+value+')').attr("value",key)); 
});
```